Stack action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Main"} was not handle by any navigaror
I am getting this error when I let the user log in and save the user information locally but it cannot be transferred to the Main screen.
The logic is that the screens in AuthenticateStackNavigator do not need to be logged in, and the features in StackNavigator must be logged in to use.
my code

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const StackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Main"
        component={BottomTabNavigator}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          gestureEnabled: false,
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const AuthenticatedStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Login"
        component={LoginScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          gestureEnabled: false,
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Register"
        component={RegisterScreen}
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'Register',
          gestureEnabled: false,
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const MainNavigator = () => {
  const {isLoading, userToken} = useAuth();
  if (isLoading) {
    <LoadingScreen />;
  }
  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={MyTheme}>
      <StatusBar hidden />
      {userToken !== null ? (
        <StackNavigator />
      ) : (
        <AuthenticatedStackNavigator />
      )}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default MainNavigator;


code login
 onSubmit: async values => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const response = await connectionApi.post('/api/auth/login', {
          email_or_username: values.email_or_username,
          password: values.password,
        });

        if (response.status === 200) {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', response.data.token);
          navigation.navigate('Main' as never);
        } else {
          const {message} = response.data;
          Alert.alert('Login Failed', message);
        }
      } catch (error: any) {
        if (error.response && error.response.data) {
          const {message} = error.response.data;
          Alert.alert('Login Failed', message);
        } else {
          console.error(error);
          Alert.alert('Login Error', 'An error occurred during login');
        }
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    },

AuthProvider
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import React, {createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';

interface AuthContextType {
  isLoading: boolean;
  userToken: string | null;
  login: () => void;
  logout: () => void;
}
const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>({
  isLoading: false,
  userToken: null,
  login: () => {},
  logout: () => {},
});

const AuthProvider = ({children}: any) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const login = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setUserToken('token');
    AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', userToken as string);
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setUserToken(null);
    AsyncStorage.removeItem('userToken');
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  const isLoggedIn = async () => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
      setUserToken(token);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    isLoggedIn();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{isLoading, userToken, login, logout}}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export default AuthProvider;


Main screen
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const renderTabIcon = ({title, icon: IconComponent, focused}: any) => (
  <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
    <IconComponent
      width={20}
      height={20}
      style={{color: focused ? colors.primary : colors.gray}}
    />
    <Text
      style={{
        fontSize: 10,
        color: focused ? colors.primary : colors.gray,
      }}>
      {title}
    </Text>
  </View>
);
const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="HomeScreen"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
      }}>
      {bottomTabs.map(({title, name, screen, icon, tabBarBadge}, index) => (
        <BottomTab.Screen
          key={index}
          name={name}
          component={screen}
          options={{
            tabBarBadge: tabBarBadge,
            tabBarBadgeStyle: {
              color: colors.white,
              fontSize: sizes.body,
            },
            tabBarIcon: ({focused}: any) =>
              renderTabIcon({icon, focused, title}),
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default BottomTabNavigator;

Some ways I have tried
Authentication
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {...} was not handled by any navigator
